# Why does AWS Glue not support SQL as the ETL language?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Currently, it supports Python & Scala, but SQL is obviously more natural & convenient to express the ETL logic.

Answer (score 1):

Glue is sold as *serverless Spark*, which makes it naturally support Python and Scala. Remember that with some boilerplate code you can use Spark SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Currently my thinking is, while Athena is built on top of Presto, Glue is built on top of Spark, the SQL grammar for Presto and Spark is not the same, if Glue expose SQL as the first class ETL language, it would cause confusion to the end user.